# accessing nodes by name/id in the network package

Tags: r, sna

In the network and sna packages, is there a way to ensure that you reliably access nodes by an arbitrary id/name, and return output using this id/name?  It appears that, even if vertex names are explicitly assigned, the packages default to using 1:n integer indexing of nodes, and I at least cannot find a way to access the internal index.  This is seen in the following example:

```
library(network)
library(sna)
set.seed(12345)
m<-matrix(rbinom(100,1,0.02),10)
diag(m) <- 0
m.sna <- as.network.matrix(m, directed = T)
network.vertex.names(m.sna) <- letters[1:10]

#note that there is a tie between 3,7 or c,g
get.neighborhood(m.sna,"c", type = "combined") # this fails to return node g/7 as part of node c's neighborhood
get.neighborhood(m.sna,3, type = "combined") # this correctly returns the node
```

The first attempt to return the neighborhood of node g/7 using the explicit vertex name fails to return its neighbor (node c/3).  The second attempt succeeds using an index (based the row of the original matrix).  However this index does not seem to be an explicit node attribute.  Is there a way to gain more control over how nodes are indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use vertex indices, but you can get those via attributes.

You can get the `"vertex.names"` attribute values like so:

```r
get.vertex.attribute(m.sna, "vertex.names")
#>  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

But that's can get a bit verbose, so you can use the `%v%` infix instead:

```r
m.sna %v% "vertex.names"
#>  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

You can then use `==` to figure out which values equal your desired vertex's name:

```r
m.sna %v% "vertex.names" == "c"
#>  [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Which you can wrap in `which()` to get that vertex's index:

```r
which(m.sna %v% "vertex.names" == "c")
#> [1] 3
```

Putting it all together gives you the following:

```r
get.neighborhood(m.sna, 
                 v = which(m.sna %v% "vertex.names" == "c"), 
                 type = "combined")
#> [1] 7
```